# I'm emulating a mps2-an385 via QEMU. How to "expose" GPIO address so that I can write to it from host like if I've attached a peripheral to the GPIOs?

Tags: emulation, qemu, gpio

I'm a student. I'm learning qemu. I'm emulating mps2-an385 machine. do you know how to read and write from gpio pins? can qemu "expose" these pins to read or write to them like if I have attached a peripheral to them?

right now I use this commandline:

```
qemu-system-arm -machine mps2-an385 -cpu cortex-m3 -kernel output/RTOSDemo.out -monitor none -nographic -serial stdio
```

Comment: Are you talking about emulation of the peripheral connected to GPIOs? You need to add (or enable if it exists) respective driver in QEMU.

Comment: @0andriy how to add a driver in qemu? anyway, I just wanted to access to write/read these address from the hostos, so that I can simulate from hostos a write to gpio like if a peripheral is attached to gpio and is indeed writing

Comment: https://cs.unibo.it/~davide.berardi6/post/20201204-1.html Have you seen this?